# XSLT file to import XML to access

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-access-2007

Need to import this xml file to access, but only get many tables without possibility to create relationship between them. I know i need XSLT file to achieve this but I dont understand it as much to do this myself. Here is XML file i am trying to import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
    <product id="28899">
        <name>
            <product_name language="gb"><![CDATA[Battery SE W910i/W380/Z555/W20i Zylo 1150 mAh Li-Ion BS PREMIUM]]></product_name>
        </name>
        <description>
            <description_text language="gb"><![CDATA[The battery is suitable for Sony Ericsson mobile phone brand. It is equipped with two IC protection circuits and it does not show memory effect. Modern lithium-ion cells enable a long-time use of mobile phone. The Premium version ensures even a longer life and reliable work.    <b>Sort</b>: Li-Ion  <b>Capacity</b>: 1150 mAh]]></description_text>
        </description>
        <category><![CDATA[Baterie Blue Star]]></category>
        <category_tree>BAT</category_tree>
        <pictures>
            <picture id="53445" url="http://partnertele.com/images/75/53445-75.jpg" main="1"/>
            <picture id="53540" url="http://partnertele.com/images/75/53540-75.jpg" main="0"/>
            <picture id="53545" url="http://partnertele.com/images/75/53545-75.jpg" main="0"/>
        </pictures>
        <price>
            <netto_price currency="EUR" amount="1.79"/>
        </price>
        <available>1</available>
        <ean>5901737168153</ean>
    </product>
</products>
```

I have to import it either in one table or more tables with an ID in each to create relationship between them. Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Mostly, this site is aimed at questions by people who are trying to solve a programming problem and answers by people who can help them past their current difficulty.  It's not really for questions of the form "Can someone write this program for me?"  There are rent-a-programmer sites for that.  Most of the people who answer questions about XSLT here are eager to help other people learn XSLT.  But if you don't know XSLT and aren't trying to learn it, well, then helping you isn't going to help anyone learn XSLT, is it?  Good luck with your task.